# How to calculate average days between events by category 1 and category 2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of shoplifting events by store and by product. I'm trying to use Python to calculate the average number of days between shoplifting events by product. My table looks like this:

```
Product   Store  Shoplifting date  Times shoplifted
1         A      8/28/2016         6
2         A      8/28/2016         6
3         A      8/28/2016         6
2         B      8/22/2016         3
1         B      8/22/2016         3
3         B      8/22/2016         3
1         C      8/18/2016         2
3         C      8/18/2016         2
4         C      8/18/2016         2
1         A      8/18/2016         5
3         A      8/18/2016         5
1         B      8/16/2016         2
1         A      8/14/2016         4
4         C      8/13/2016         1
3         A      8/12/2016         4
2         A      8/12/2016         4
```

Product 1 was stolen from Store A on 8/28, 8/18, and 8/14 (10 days and 4 days between thefts) and from Store B on 8/22 and 8/16 (8 days), for an average of (10 + 4 + 8) / 3 = 7.33 days. So for Product 1 expected results would be:

```
Product    Days between shoplifting
1          7.33
```

The "Times shoplifted" column is the cumulative number of times the store has been shoplifted. It increases with each shoplifting event. So, for instance, on 8/28/2016, Store A was shoplifted of items 1, 2, and 3. That was the 6th time the store had been shoplifted from.

I am trying to calculate the average number of days between shoplifting by product. I've been writing a lot of for loops and it's getting quite messy so I'd like a cleaner way to do it. I'm not too familiar with Pandas, but I do believe it has some handy time processing ability...? How would you solve this problem in Pandas? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd sort the dataframe by `Shoplifting date` first, then for each group, `diff` will give you time deltas, and `mean` will average them.

```
df.sort_values('Shoplifting date').groupby(
    'Product'
)['Shoplifting date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean()).dropna()

Product
1      0 days
3      0 days
582   10 days
650    4 days
Name: Shoplifting date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: this is almost what I need, but not quite. It needs to also take into account the store. In the extract I posted, there's no repeat of the same item stolen from the same store but it does occur deep in the data. For example, let's say Item 1 was stolen from Store A and stolen again from Store A 10 days later. At Store B, it was stolen twice with 6 days between. So the average would be 8 days. It dates between thefts at Store A and Store B don't matter at all.

Comment: @Greg It's difficult when you don't post an example of what you want to see as a result and you also don't post enough data to demonstrate the main issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize it's confusing. I think I'm in over my head on this one. The table is over 1 million rows long and I can't find any suitable section to extract but I know it's in there somewhere. I'll dig around and see if I can make it clearer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Greg make it up.  If you know what it looks like.